# How can I strip new line character from my response

Tags: json, strip

My code is -

```
import json

f = open('AcceptanceCriteria.json')
data = json.load(f,strict=False)
for criteria in data['acceptanceCriteria']: 
    print(criteria)
```

Response getting is -

```
{'criteria': 'Assets are grouped at a Fabric level with each Fabric consisting of APICs and\nSwitches.'}
{'criteria': 'Cloud Network Software landing page shows the specified columns: Risk Level,\nFabric, Software Type, Current Release, Selected Release, Assets, and Suggestions.'}
```

how can I get rid of `\n` from the response

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the content of each criteria entry is an object with a string valued property with key 'criteria', so the below should work fine:

I renamed the 'criteria' variable to make it more obvious it's an entry in an array. **Updated to correct access syntax for string key in the dictionary structure, as pointed out by [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick) in the comments**

```js
for criteriaEntry in data['acceptanceCriteria']: 
    print(criteriaEntry['criteria'].replace("\n", ""))
```

Comment: still throwing this error - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'criteria'

Comment: Should be `criteriaEntry['criteria'].replace("\n", " ")`

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much